# GIT how to create a repo on virtual machine

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I want let my team work on a Windows Virtual Machine where everyone has already its own access with user/pwd.

I want to store the repo in G:\repo and let each developer to clone from it.

I need to understand which are best practices for create local repository and let other clone it for development usage (till commit and push)

Unfortunatelly a remote repo is forbidden for the moment, so I'm trying this workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc).

1. Run `git init G:\repo --bare` to initialize bare git repository in this directory. With `--bare` option you create the repository without working directory.
2. As you say "remote repo is forbidden", I can guess that you can't make this repository available over HTTP(S) to other team members. In such case, you could share G:\repo directory on your LAN. Access the repository using the file:// access schema and including the UNC path to the repository `file://\\server\repo`. It's now time to import the initial data to the repository, so run `git clone file://\\server\repo`.
3. Put the contents of your project to the cloned repository, `git add` & `git commit` them to master.
4. `git push --set-upstream origin master` the project's data to the remote bare repository on your virtual machine.

Comment: ok, but I unfortunatelly get this output when pushing: "The following errors were reported during push: refs/heads/master, Failed to rename lockfile to 'G:/InterfaceMasterRepo/refs/heads/master': Access is denied."

Comment: @albert you haven't provided enough NTFS / share permissions to G:\InterfaceMasterRepo. That's why you are getting "Access is denied" error now.